# Google Android TTS human readable names of voices

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) in my application. I want to add a setting that allows the user to select a voice. I get list of voices from current TTS engine (com.google.android.tts, I need only Chinese voices) and their names are added in the settings:

```
val voices = tts.voices.filter {it.locale == Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE}
```

Their names look completely unreadable, for example:

```
cmn-cn-x-ssa-local
cmn-cn-x-ccc-network
cmn-cn-x-ccd-local
```

Is there a way to get human-readable names of voices? Or at least get their gender?

For example, [TextToSpeech.EngineInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.EngineInfo) contains a **name** field containing a unique name for the engine and a **label** field containing a human-readable name. Maybe there is something similar for voices too?

Answer (score 1):

I have formatted this way, maybe can be improved but at least look's better than default listing.

```
String sal = voices.get(e).name;

            if(sal.contains("#")) {

                String[] pre = sal.split("#");
                String sec = pre[1].replace("_", " ");
                sec = sec.replace("-", " ");
                String[] sal2 = pre[0].split("-");
                sal = sal2[0] + "_" + sal2[1].toUpperCase() + " (" + utils.capitalize(sec) + ")";
            }

            if(sal.contains("-x-")) {

                String[] noSal = sal.split("-x-");
                String[] noSal2 = noSal[0].split("-");
                String noSal3 = noSal[1].replace("-", " ");
                sal  = noSal2[0] + "_" + noSal2[1].toUpperCase() + " (" + utils.capitalize(noSal3) + ")";
            }

            if(sal.contains("-")){
                String[] finalSal = sal.split("-");
                sal = finalSal[0] + "_" + finalSal[1] + " (" + utils.capitalize(finalSal[2]) + ")";
            }
```

utils.capitalize() it's a little function to capitalize words.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of method for Flutter (compatible for all platforms):

```dart
class AnyClass {
  static String voiceNameToReadableVoiceName(String rawVoiceName) {
    // For non parsable voice name (TTS other than Android)
    if (rawVoiceName.contains(' ')) {
      return rawVoiceName;
    }

    // Example: 'fr-CA#female_1-local' -> 'fr_CA - Female 1 Local'
    if (rawVoiceName.contains('#')) {
      List<String> pre = rawVoiceName.split('#');
      String sec = pre[1].replaceAll('_', ' ');
      sec = sec.replaceAll('-', ' ');
      if (pre[0].contains('-')) {
        List<String> sal2 = pre[0].split('-');
        return '${sal2[0]}_${sal2[1]} - ${sec.toAllWordsCapitalized()}';
      }
    }

    // Example: 'fr-CA-x-cad-local' -> 'fr_CA - Cad Local'
    if (rawVoiceName.contains('-x-')) {
      List<String> noSal = rawVoiceName.split('-x-');
      if (noSal[0].contains('-')) {
        List<String> noSal2 = noSal[0].split('-');
        String noSal3 = noSal[1].replaceAll('-', ' ');
        return '${noSal2[0]}_${noSal2[1]} - ${noSal3.toAllWordsCapitalized()}';
      }
    }

    // Example: 'fr-CA-language' -> 'fr_CA - Language'
    if (rawVoiceName.contains('-')) {
      List<String> finalSal = rawVoiceName.split('-');
      if (finalSal.length >= 3) {
        return '${finalSal[0]}_${finalSal[1]} - ${finalSal[2].toAllWordsCapitalized()}';
      }
    }

    // Fallback to default if not parsed
    return rawVoiceName;
  }
}

// Extension for String
extension StringExtend on String {
  String toFirstWordCapitalized() {
    if (length > 0) {
      return '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  String toAllWordsCapitalized() {
    // Get list of words
    List<String> words = replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ').split(' ');
    // Capitalize all words
    words = words.map((str) => str.toFirstWordCapitalized()).toList();
    // recreate the phrase
    return words.join(' ');
  }
}
```